# Sequence-generating functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, soft-question

I have a pretty simple question, but let me provide a bit of background.

I find it ocasionally useful to define a sequence of functions. For example, when studying the Taylor expansion of some $f$, I usually define a sequence $f_n := \{f^{(1)}(x), f^{(2)}(x), ..., f^{(n)}(x)\}$; i.e. a sequence of continuous functions if we assume each derivative exists. It is not a great leap to extend this to a function defining this sequence with varying $x$; something like

$$f_n(x) := \{f^{(1)}(x), f^{(2)}(x), ..., f^{(n)}(x)\}$$

For example, for $f(x)=\cos(x)$ we would have

$$f_n(0) := \{f^{(1)}(0), f^{(2)}(0), ...\}=\{0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1,...\}$$

which is to my eyes a pretty straightforward way to conceive (and write) the $f^{(n)}$ coefficients of the expansion of $\cos x$.

Clearly, $f_n(0)$ is simply a "regular" sequence, since its elements are real numbers. It has no special property. However, the same can not be said of $f_n(x)$, since its elements are functions, not numbers. I suppose this means $f_n(x)$ is a mapping from a set of functions to a set of numbers.

Of course, $f_n(x)$ needs not be restricted to the derivatives of some $f$. I don't see how any arbitrary $f_n(x)=\{g(x), h(x), ...\}$ isn't justified as well.

Of course I don't pretend to be the inventor of a such a simple concept. However, my college books don't have any theory on a concept such as a sequence of functions. I wonder if there's any formal theory and stablished notation around this idea (since the notation I've been using is simply what I found intuitive). I'd be particularly interested in any book where this is covered in detail.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your $f_n(x)$ is actually a mapping from set of numbers (natural numbers) to set of functions, not from set of functions - it makes no sense to speak about value of your mapping on function $|\sin(x)|$, but it makes total sense to speak about value of your mapping on number $3$ - it's just function $f_3(x)$.

Yes, sequences of functions are standard concept. For example, in analysis there is conception of "uniform convergence", which is a special requirement for how exactly sequence of functions should converge to another function, that has some nice properties. See, for example, Chapter 7 "Sequences and Series of Functions" of Baby Rudin.